# Forgot password on Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 - how to reset?

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, tablet, locked-out

I've lost my password on my almost new Samsung Galaxy S4. Now I can't unlock the tablet, and I can't shut it down since all these actions require the password. The only thing I can do is restarting it.

Now I want to reset it to factory settings, so I can set a new password. However, all the guides to a hard reset say you have to turn it off first. This I cannot do since it requires the password.

How can I reset or shut down the tablet without a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have time, let the battery drain. Then power up the tablet with the charger. Press <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> to go to recovery (until you see the recovery screen) and reset the tablet.
2. If not, hold <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> for up to 45 seconds to restart the tablet. When it restarts, press <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> to go to recovery (until you see the recovery screen) and reset the tablet.

Sources:

[Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 Reset Guide: How to Master Reset, Reset Network Settings, Soft Reset your Tablet](https://thedroidguy.com/2018/10/samsung-galaxy-tab-s4-reset-guide-how-to-master-reset-reset-network-settings-soft-reset-your-tablet-1091652)

[Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 - Factory Data Reset (Powered Off)](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-219478/)

Comment: Option 2 did it, thanks. 15 seconds were enough.

Comment: Doesn't that trigger FRP (factory-reset protection) without the account being removed prior to reset? Be sure to check if you can run the initial setup before you "give away" the device, @cheeesus – or the "receiver" won't be that happy…

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the advice, but at the moment, the device is staying with me.